# Separate column value as a row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as shown here:

```
Name          First Value      Second Value
---------------------------------------------
BestBuy       700               -250
```

The code that I'm using is:

```
SELECT Name, First Value, Second Value
FROM TABLE_A
```

What I want is this:

```
Name          First Value
----------------------------
BestBuy        700 
BestBuy       -250
```

The pending value will now be an additional value under first value i.e. instead of getting an extra column value, I have to add an additional line. Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
select a.name, v.market_value
from table_a a
cross apply  (values (market_value), (pending_value)) v(market_value);
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. I'm trying to apply the above logic to my code but it is throwing an error -  Expecting ID or QUOTED_ID.

Comment: @HSManohar Gordon was missing the actual APPLY.  see edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`, as in:

```
SELECT Name, [Market Value] FROM TABLE_A
UNION ALL 
SELECT Name, [Pending Value] FROM TABLE_A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `unpivot` like below:

```
SELECT [Name], val AS [Market Value]
FROM @t t
UNPIVOT
(
  val for col in ([Market Value], [Pending Value])
) UPVT
```

**[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=898c429288bc7f09f509efe828301adc)**

Comment: I am using a few left joins and outer apply in my code. So if I use this logic, I am unable to join other tables to the main table. It says - multi-part identifier could not be bound.